# The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect in Entity Framework. Constant in left join

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, join, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to do a left join in an EF query. I'm getting the following error:

> Error CS1941  The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is
>   incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'GroupJoin'

and here is the C# code:

```
var foo = from m in db.ClientMasters
                      join a in db.Orders on new { m.Id, Status = "N" } equals new { a.ClientID, a.Status } into a_join
                      from a in a_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { m.ClientID, a.ID };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The column names have to match in the join; here is the corrected code:

```
var foo = from m in db.ClientMasters
                      join a in db.Orders on new { ClientID = m.Id, Status = "N" } equals new { a.ClientID, a.Status } into a_join
                      from a in a_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
                      select new { ClientID = m.Id, OrderId = a.Id };
```