# Left Join in LINQ Query and ToList

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I'm trying to apply a join table in linq using the join function. But I get an error:

> Error CS1941 The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is
>   invalid. Type inference failed in invoking "GroupJoin" element.

```
var query = from c in repos.GetTable<Table1>()
                            join ct in repos.GetTable<Table2>()
                            on c.Nr_PY equals ct.Nr_PY1 into g
                            from ct in g.DefaultIfEmpty()

                            select new
                            {
                                ct.Nr_PY1,
                                c.Name,

                            }.ToList();
```

Can you help me what's wrong with this code?

Thank you for your help

Comment: What is the return type of `repos.GetTable<T>()`?

Comment: From DataClasses1DataContext repos = new DataClasses1DataContext();   I have 2 tables Table1 and Table2. Linq to SQL.

Comment: What are the types of `Nr_PY` and `Nr_PY1` ?

Comment: This is Name Column in Table2 and Table1

Comment: @PYJTERxXx please include you model and repo code. We need more details in order to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect in Entity Framework. Constant in left join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33370600/the-type-of-one-of-the-expressions-in-the-join-clause-is-incorrect-in-entity-fra)

Answer (score 0):

Per the answer in my "duplicate" comment, the column names in the join need to be the same. In your case, it'd be:

```c#
join ct in repos.GetTable<Table2>()
on c.Nr_PY equals new { Nr_PY = ct.Nr_PY1 } into g
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query has more than one error first you can't convert `Anonymous type` to `IList` you will get following Error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Collections.Generic.List AnonymousType#1 to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List

so you can change you code like this :

```
 var query = (from c in repos.GetTable<Table1>()
                        join ct in repos.GetTable<Table2>()
                        on c.Nr_PY equals ct.Nr_PY1 into g
                        from ct in g.DefaultIfEmpty()

                        select new myclass
                        {
                            value1=ct.Nr_PY1,
                            value2=c.Name,

                        }).ToList();
```

and second error is Nr_PY and Nr_PY1 doesn't have exactly same type.

here is a sql fiddle :
https://dotnetfiddle.net/SBXLj2